# How to Remove Double Quotes from a Particular part in a String?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

If String contains lots of DoubleQuotes how to delete particular DoubleQuote using C#

Requirement :

Normal :

```
Update "3D Text 1" "Text="3D Text"","Weight=Normal","Italics=False","Name=Arial","Base Embedding=Left to Right","Size=50"
```

Output Will have to come like this

```
Update "3D Text 1" "Text=3D Text","Weight=Normal","Italics=False","Name=Arial","Base Embedding=Left to Right","Size=50"
```

Here I removed the Double Quotes in `3D Text`; is it possible to do this programmatically? I dont want to remove all the DoubleQuotes.

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding the proper syntax rules for a well-formed string, it will be difficult to determine which quotes are desired and which aren't.

Perhaps you can move further up the process and remove the quotes before forming string?

Comment: This is not the solution sir..I need to remove this after execution ..i have to get whole line as a script and have to split things up.Because this is used in Powershell.

Comment: I hand you a piece of paper with the numbers 91735712 and ask you to add the three numbers up. What's the answer?